# Error while Uploading a file using FormData Ajax Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, ajax

I have been trying to load a multiple file HTML input using Ajax and Django, I know that there are a bunch of questions related to this problem here in StackOverflow but none of the methods have worked for me. I am trying to use a single web page. I would appreciate any recommendation:

HTML Code: This code is inserted also with a click function using ajax, that is why there are a lot of + symbols and everything is inside quotation marks

```
+'<form id="reclamo" action="{% url "denuncia" %}" method="post" enctype="multiport/form-data">'
+'{% csrf_token %}'+'<label for="files">Adjuntos:</label>'+'<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>'
+'<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple><br><br>'
+'<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Reportar">'
+"</form>"
```

And this one is the Ajax code:

```
$(document).on('submit','#reclamo',function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var frm = new FormData($('#reclamo').get(0));
 $.ajax({
  url: "/denuncia/",
  type: "POST",
  data: frm,
  cache:false,
  proccessData: false,
  contentType: false,
  headers:{
      'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}'
    },
  success: function(result){
      if (result == 'saved') {
        alert('ha sido creada con exito')
      }
      }
  });
})
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
at e (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at xb (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Function.r.param (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Function.ajax (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> ((index):226)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
```

Comment: i assume that the problem is with contructor formData.
var frm = new FormData();

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your data attribute is misspelled. Not sure if this solves it, just saw it. Try edit it to formData.